# Make app start and remain in landscape mode

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, landscape, uiinterfaceorientation

How can I start my app in landscape mode, and keep the screen rotation that way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || 
   interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement the view controller's `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method and `return  UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation);`

Also set the `Info.plist` keys `UIInterfaceOrientation` and `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` to `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft` and `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`. `UIInterfaceOrientation` will take a single value so assign one of them and assign both of them to `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations`.